# Should I post a comment with a link to "How do I ask a good question" when I flag a question as "Unclear what you are asking"?

Tags: discussion, support

So when you flag a question as a duplicate StackOverflow automatically posts a comment saying that you think the question is a duplicate of.. [duplicate question link]

Today I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29940135/2987066) as "Unclear what you are asking" as it just says:

> "I have problem with my App i made choose button to select file from
>   PC but i got exception if i didn't choose any files hope anyone can
>   help thanks"

with an image below.

I was wondering whether I should post a comment with a link to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help the user know how to post a good question

and whether others think it would be a good idea to have that comment happen  automatically like the duplicate question comment or whether it would be annoying / patronising?

Comment: I use [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [Welcome to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) depending on the nature and content of the question. I have others sitting in a text editor ready for copy and paste but those three receive the most attention; sometimes in combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular question is horrible, for several reasons.

- the title does not describe the problem
- the body of the post does not describe the problem
- there is an image of source code (?) and error message (?) -- I'd need to download the image and view it at 100% to read it
- it does not contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how to reproduce the error
- (minor, and fixable by others) the text does not contain any punctuation, lowercase self referential 'i', does *not* end with a question mark but does end with 'thanks'.

**Yes**, the author needs to be pointed to the Help Center. In addition, he might well be advised to take the [Short and Friendly Introductory Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

In advance of a question being closed/put on hold, I don't see a problem with trying to educate a user that asks questions that have close votes against them.

Once the question is actually put on hold, they get that information displayed below their post:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Oh yea, that's a good point. In this case the question has actually been put on hold for "Marked as Duplicate" I feel that in this case this leaves the issue that it is a bad question unresolved. I will go with @Jeeped's point and post a comment directing the user in the direction of one of those links